# Changing frequency of input clock port (FPGA)

Tags: fpga, clock

I', using xilinx ultrascale FPGA (xcku025-ffva-1-a)

I am referring to application notes provided by xilinx.

I am going to use the reference code provided in xapp1315.

In this reference code, an external clock of 100 MHz enters to FPGA, passes IBUFDS_DIFF_OUT, and then goes to idelaye3.
[image]

I am going to design my top file containing this logic as shown in the picture below

The reference code  should receive 100 MHZ external clocks (go to IBUFDS), but my top design has only 50 MHZ external clocks.

[image]

What's the best way to solve a case like this?

Comment: Modify the reference code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about IDELAYE3 of Xilinx FPGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481604/question-about-idelaye3-of-xilinx-fpga)

Comment: You have already asked this question. If you have more information, edit the existing question instead of opening a duplicate.

Comment: oh. sorry, I didn't know there was an answer to the previous one, so I posted a new question and forgot to delete the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as you have drawn your block diagram; the IBUFDS_DIFF_OUT is an input buffer and as such it may only be connected directly to the proper IO pins; it cannot be driven from within the FPGA.  What you need to do is edit the reference design to use a 50 MHz input clock.  This could be as simple as changing the settings of an existing MMCM or PLL.  Or maybe you need to add an MMCM or PLL instance.